# How to make user select from multiple choice's line in android

Tags: android, forms, selection, between

I would like to know how to make the user select some value on line like the example I show you in the attachment.
[settings from tinder app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfvSD.jpg)

I would like to know too how to make the user select values between 2 values (like in the pic I'm showing you)

I thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [SeekBar](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-seekbar-example/) controller.

Answer (score 0):

To select from a range of values like the attachment that you provided, consider using [SeekBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html)

To select one of two values, consider using [Switch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html)